# Demonic Strategies for Claustrophobia

Tags: claustrophobia

I have recently begun playing Claustrophobia [<sup>BGG</sup>](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/36932/claustrophobia) and have found myself playing the human side almost every time. The problem I encounter is - I'm *winning*. This is not usually a problem for me. But something about Claustrophobia has clicked for me, and I'm winning. A lot. It's making people not want to play with me.

We have discovered the handicaps, and my family has agreed to have the demon side start with 7 Threat Points instead of the usual 4, but I think that the game is more inherently balanced than our results would indicate.

So: What strategies do successful demon players pursue?

- Do you spend the first *n* turns building up Threat?
- Which powers do you consistently activate?
- Event Cards - worth it or not?
- Which humans are your first targets? (Redeemer, right?)

Please help my opponents! (And me, should I ever get to play the demon side...)

Comment: I have to admit I don't know the game, and this is not exactly an answer to your question, so feel free to mod me into oblivion if it doesn't make sense. But here's my contribution: you could consider having the participants *bid* on being allowed to be human - have players say, "I'm willing to be human if the demons start with 6 threat points", "I'll raise it to 8", "Alright, you get it". If the players have somewhat similar level, this should balance out the sides.

Comment: That's an interesting idea - not an answer to this question, but an interesting answer to another question!

Comment: @Erik P - also, I think the "advanced" game may in fact be a "name that tune" style auction mechanic, where you bid lower and lower numbers of points with which you then buy demons / teammates, advantages / events, etc.. I'll have to check my rulebook at home.

Comment: The advanced game has a mechanic exactly like that.  You actually bid on how many points you'll use to build the human team.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My experience from playing both sides is that the Demons win more often than not.

For the demon player:

1. Try to always have two troglodyte packs on the board, ideally from two sides, two packs of 3 troglodytes is very hard on the humans.  Keep them replenished, only power them up (ravenous, etc.) for sure hits or to position in front or behind.
2. Attack the human with the lowest armor, if equal then attack human with most wounds, if equal then attack redeemer
3. Event cards are very much worth it, grab them whenever you can
4. The big demon usually isn't needed to win.  Troglodyte swarms are great on their own.

Answer (score 0):

For me I find that the demon generally wins and unlike you I hardly ever play the Human Player. It really depends on the scenario you're playing, see if you're playing the Survivors(scenario one) I would highly recommend using troglodytes to wound as many people as deeply as you can and then bring your demon out and use his special power (when the target is wounded get extra combat) to just finish each of them off in one swipe. See - you just gotta find the tactic!